# call a function after rendering ends react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which gets all the inputs rendered (querySelector) in order to execute other stuff and also is called by the "onChange" method of a component I have in order to detect if other inputs were added.

The main problem here is that when useEffect() is called, for some reason not all the inputs are detected, for example if in the DOM there are 3 inputs it only detects 2 (the last input added is not being detected as you can see in the example).

[image: 2 of 3 detected]

what I think is happening is that the querySelector function ends before the other input is rendered so thats why only the last one added is not being detected. I tried adding a setTimeout() function but that is not a good practice...

Any recommendations?

```
const onChangeQuery = (e) => {
    //some other code here...

    selectFirstOpt();
};

useEffect(() => {
    selectFirstOpt();
  },[])

const selectFirstOpt = () => {
    let selects = document.querySelectorAll(".rule--field > select");
    if(!selects.length) return;

    selects.forEach((select) => {
      let firstOpt = select.options[0];
      if(firstOpt.value === "") firstOpt.innerText = "select an option";
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be directly interacting with the DOM at all in React.  Why do you need to?  Isn't the rendering of these elements driven by state, and you could just examine the current state?

Comment: For some reason, the last input added is not being detected by the querySelector. And I'm using a library which creates those inputs, so I don't have the control of it. Thats why the only way I can handle those inputs is by using querySelector

Comment: You may need to consult with the library's documentation or vendor then.  We don't know anything about that.  But we do know that (1) direct DOM manipulation in React is almost always the wrong approach and (2) if `document.querySelectorAll` doesn't find it then it's not in the DOM at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use useRef with useEffect. Also using useRef you can work on the element instead of using selectors to change element values.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
...
/* In your react hook function*/
const first = useRef();
const second = useRef();
...
useEffect(() => {
first.current.value = "value";
second.current.value = "changed";
}, [first, second])
...
/* in your return function */
<input type="text" ref={first} />
<input type="text" ref={second} />
```

This will change the value of the inputs as soon as they are loaded correctly, it is important to add useRef variables or constants into useEffect square brackets.

Comment: Those inputs are generated by a library I'm using so I don't have the control to add a ref value in there :(

Comment: I actually don't know how those inputs are generated but i have few ideas.
1. If the library is called by a function, you could create a state which updates just after the function has been executed, that way using useEffect you could listen to that state and run your function.
2. similarly to my previous idea, create a state which will update at the end of the return statement something like {nstate === false && setnstate(true)}, listen to that state and run your function.